# Как передать авторизацию из selenium в requests?

Tags: python, selenium, requests

Я смог передать куки, но авторизация не передаётся. (Я пытаюсь передать данные с сайта nike.com)
Возможно, можно как-то всё передать из селениума, кроме куки?
Ещё я заметил, что в определённых запросах в headers есть пункт Authorization с кучей символов, видимо это токен авторизации. Может headers можно как-то передавать из селениума?

Comment: Возможно, придется использовать selenium wire: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64411057/5909792

Comment: Не получается: из-за проблем с сертификатом я не могу войти в аккаунт. Решить проблему эту я не смог